# Illegal ambiguous match on configurable attribute "deps" in //tensorflow/core/grappler/costs:utils: when trying to build Tensorflow with GPU support

Tags: ubuntu, bazel, tensorflow

I am trying to build Tensorflow on Ubuntu with the command `bazel build --config=opt --cxxopt="-D_GLIBCXX_USE_CXX11_ABI=0" --config=cuda //tensorflow/tools/pip_package:build_pip_package`
 but I get the following error after running `./configure`:

```
Illegal ambiguous match on configurable attribute "deps" in //tensorflow/core/grappler/costs:utils:
@local_config_cuda//cuda:using_clang
@local_config_cuda//cuda:using_nvcc
Multiple matches are not allowed unless one is unambiguously more specialized.
ERROR: Analysis of target '//tensorflow/tools/pip_package:build_pip_package' failed; build aborted
INFO: Elapsed time: 30.960s
FAILED: Build did NOT complete successfully (91 packages loaded)
```

I am not sure what happened. It seems that there is a conflict between using clang and nvcc, but I don't think I've specified using nvcc anywhere during the configuration process. `./configure` should have finished without any issue.

Strangely I am not able to find any such bug report on the internet.

Could it be the case that I installed CUDA incorrectly, or is it more likely a bug with the `tensorflow` configuration?

- Ubuntu 16.04 LTS
- CUDA 8.0
- cuDnn 7.0.1

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Not sure if it would be of help to anybody else but apparently during the configuration process I answered "yes" to using `clang` as a compiler. I then answered "no" and used `gcc` as a host for `nvcc`; the build finished fine.

Answer (score 10):

You need to use `--config=cuda_clang` in your Bazel command, e.g.:

```
bazel build --config=opt --config=cuda_clang //tensorflow/tools/pip_package:build_pip_package
```

Answer (score 1):

I also meet this issue where I try to compile TF using different compilers on Ubuntu 16.04, there are two options to solve this issue:

`1. Do you want to use clang as CUDA compiler? [y/N]` choose **y**, here you use **clang** as the backend cuda code compiler, then you can use command:
`bazel build --config=opt --config=cuda_clang //tensorflow/tools/pip_package:build_pip_package`.

`2. Do you want to use clang as CUDA compiler? [y/N]` choose **N**, here you use **nvcc** as the backend cuda code compiler, then you can use command:
`bazel build --config=opt --config=cuda //tensorflow/tools/pip_package:build_pip_package`.

[CUDA is supported in llvm 3.9](https://llvm.org/docs/CompileCudaWithLLVM.html), if using clang as the cuda code compiler, clang 3.9 or higher version is needed. [You will need CUDA 7.0, 7.5, or 8.0 to compile with clang](https://llvm.org/docs/CompileCudaWithLLVM.html), CUDA 9.0 or higher version is not supported yet.
[A related topic in TF Github](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/11043), hope this is useful.